# JS function being called twice?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-in-loop

I can't seem to find the bug that's making the code run twice, and JSFiddle isn't working for me so I can't double check if it's the editor.

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: 9,
    address: ["5242", "drank avenue"]
};
friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: 8,
    address: ["3368", "pool lane"]
};

var list = function(person)
{
    for (var friendName in person)
        console.log(friendName);
};

list(friends);
```

---

```
Output:
bill
steve
bill
steve
```

Comment: Why isn't JSFiddle working for you, seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/zjtgwd9u/ ?

Comment: … and doesn't show the problem you are having (which therefore isn't in the code you've put in the question).

Comment: hey stumped, your codes go fine with jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heob13te/2/

Comment: Not sure the Internet's kinda unreliable here and maybe it couldn't fun jsfiddle. Thank you for reconfirming it!

Comment: @Quentin this is my whole code but I'm using CodeAcademy's online editor so maybe that was buggy.

Comment: IIRC, the Code Academy site doesn't clear out the console when it runs.  On your browser, there is an option to clear the console -- so you may have run the program twice and that is why you are seeing the output twice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I cut and pasted the code you posted into my JavaScript console and the result was:

```
bill
steve
```

Somewhere, in your original code, you must be calling the function twice.

Choose a place in the code — in this case I would choose the top of your `list` function — and put a

```
debugger;
```

statement there, and open the JavaScript console.

There will be an option in that debugger to see a stack trace.  The stack trace will let you see exactly where a function was called from, so you can see if it is being called from two different points.

If that doesn't work, move the debugger statement to right above this line:

```
friends.bill = {
```

and repeat until you find the problem.